# React search option in the table

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is the total code that I currently have.

```
import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";

const FetchStocks = () => {
const API_KEY = "apiKey1";
const API_KEY2 = "apiKey2";
const API_KEY3 = "apiKey3";
const [data, setData] = useState({ StockSymbols: null, StockName: null, StockIndustry: null })
const [MSFT, setMSFT] = useState({ MSFTSymbols: null, MSFTName: null, MSFTIndustry: null })
const [AA, setAA] = useState({ AASymbols: null, AAName: null, AAIndustry: null })
const [BABA, setBABA] = useState({ BABASymbols: null, BABAName: null, BABAIndustry: null })
const [SAIC, setSAIC] = useState({ SAICSymbols: null, SAICName: null, SAICIndustry: null })
const [search, setSearch] = useState < string > ('');

useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (data) {
                setData({
                    StockSymbols: data['Symbol'],
                    StockName: data['Name'],
                    StockIndustry: data['Industry']
                })
            })

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=MSFT&apikey=${API_KEY2}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (MSFT) {
                setMSFT({
                    MSFTSymbols: MSFT['Symbol'],
                    MSFTName: MSFT['Name'],
                    MSFTIndustry: MSFT['Industry']
                })
            })

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=AA&apikey=${API_KEY3}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (AA) {
                setAA({
                    AASymbols: AA['Symbol'],
                    AAName: AA['Name'],
                    AAIndustry: AA['Industry']
                })
            })

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=BABA&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (BABA) {
                setBABA({
                    BABASymbols: BABA['Symbol'],
                    BABAName: BABA['Name'],
                    BABAIndustry: BABA['Industry']
                })
            })

    fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=SAIC&apikey=${API_KEY2}`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function (SAIC) {
                setSAIC({
                    SAICSymbols: SAIC['Symbol'],
                    SAICName: SAIC['Name'],
                    SAICIndustry: SAIC['Industry']
                })
            })
}, [])



const table = {
    columns: [
        { headerName: "Symbol", field: "symbol" },
        { headerName: "Name", field: "name" },
        { headerName: "Industry", field: "industry" }
    ],

    rowData: [
        { symbol: `${data.StockSymbols}`, name: `${data.StockName}`, industry: `${data.StockIndustry}` },
        { symbol: `${MSFT.MSFTSymbols}`, name: `${MSFT.MSFTName}`, industry: `${MSFT.MSFTIndustry}` },
        { symbol: `${AA.AASymbols}`, name: `${AA.AAName}`, industry: `${AA.AAIndustry}` },
        { symbol: `${BABA.BABASymbols}`, name: `${BABA.BABAName}`, industry: `${BABA.BABAIndustry}` },
        { symbol: `${SAIC.SAICSymbols}`, name: `${SAIC.SAICName}`, industry: `${SAIC.SAICIndustry}` }
    ],
}

let containerStyle = {
    height: 500,
    width: 700
}

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search Stock" />
        </div>
        <div
            className="ag-theme-balham"
            style={containerStyle}
        >
            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={table.columns}
                rowData={table.rowData}
                pagination={true}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
)
};

export default FetchStocks;
```

I'm trying to make search bar for the symbols column in the table.

[This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soM1O.png)

However, I'm concerned because every element in the table is fetched and saved in differenct const (eg. data, MSFT, AA).

How would I be able to create a search bar that searches by the stock symbol in the table?

Comment: If your api key are real, please hide it or change it with different values.

Comment: Are you using typescript with react? If not type declaration is not allowed like here `const [search, setSearch] = useState < string > ('');`

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way I can think of is to use `filter` method on 'rowData' property of 'table'.

```
rowData: [
    {
        symbol: `${data.StockSymbols}`,
        name: `${data.StockName}`,
        industry: `${data.StockIndustry}`
    }
].filter((data) => {
    return data.name.includes(search);
})
```

Add `setSearch` to onChange eventHandler of input Element.

In here, I have shown to use name of the stock, you can also use industry and filter based on that.

Attached, codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ag-react-table-filter-kqcqt?file=/src/Table.js)